# OPTION STRICT OFF become OPTION STRICT ON

Tags: vb.net

I have a project that I am trying to make OPTION STRICT ON instead of OPTION STRICT OFF.  Is there a way to automatically amend the code based on what the compiler does e.g. if there is a statements that says:

```
dim strTest As String = "1"
dim intTest As Integer =  strTest
```

Then automatically change this to:

```
dim strTest As String = "1"
dim intTest As Integer = cint(strTest)
```

Also is there a way of seeing how many errors there are in total in Visual Studio? At the moment it is only showing 102 errors.

Comment: If you start this effort then why use the old compatibility functions like CInt? Use the methods offered by the framework like Convert.ToInt32, Int32.TryParse, Int32.Parse

Comment: @Steve Why do you say the [type conversion functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx) are "old compatibility functions"?  According to the docs, they are compiled inline, and so are better performing vs. a function call to the `Convert` methods.  I'm curious, because I use them all the time, but maybe I'm old fashioned.

Comment: To answer your minor question, no, the Error List is limited to 100 errors (plus a few others depending on context).  I guess this is to avoid performance loss in VS.

Comment: @Mark I see, well VB.NET is not my main language of work. So perhaps you are right in your coding. Nevertheless I feel them out of place in the great NET scheme. But this is an opinion and it is an opinion of mine.

Comment: `CInt` not legacy at all.  The names derive from VB6 functions but MSDN makes it clear these are optimized to call various other System.Convert ops.  CInt also allows narrowing conversions under Option Strict.  For instance, `CInt("3.14")` works while `Convert.ToInt32("3.14")` will throw an exception. That said, I too think the System convert functions make it clearer what is going on.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289509(v=vs.71).aspx where C??? (like CInt), CType and System.Convert are compared

Comment: I think what you want can't be done without creating your own code.  One trick you can use, when you double-click the error in the error list, VS will take you to the offending line in the code.  Also to avoid this in the future, change the global options for VB, so that every project you start will have `OPTION STRICT` ON